# Google playstore app unable to access api endpoints

Tags: ionic-framework

When I build and run my ionic app, it works well and is able to access the remote endpoints. When I build a release and upload it to google playstore, it's updated well, but when I download and install it, the app is unable to access the endpoints. Everything on the server looks and works fine. What could be the cause of this kind of issue?

Comment: check your url is http or https

Comment: Everything is fine and works well when I test the app before updating it on playstore. even when I use the local version of my app, it still works well, but the play store update doesn't.

Comment: can you share your baseurl ?

Comment: Base url is https://api.twalako.com/

Comment: in android 8 up http not working. i.e you can set http to https or to add "https://api.twalako.com/" in network.xml file